# Insert into mysql star rating through ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, rate

Well folks I'm in trouble I'm the star rating system practically running but I am not able to insert in the table star rating chosen by ajax needed a little help the code I have done so.

Script

```
    <script>
        // rating script
        $(function(){ 
            $("#sent-form-msg").hide();

            $('.rate-btn').hover(function(){
                $('.rate-btn').removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
                var therate = $(this).attr('id');
                for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
                    $('.rate-btn-'+i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
                };
            });

            $('.rate-btn').click(function(){    
                var therate = $(this).attr('id');
                var dataRate = 'act=rate&post_id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>&user_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>&rate='+therate; //
                $('.rate-btn').removeClass('rate-btn-active');
                for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
                    $('.rate-btn-'+i).addClass('rate-btn-active');
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "ajax/processa_avaliacao.php",
                    data: dataRate,
                    success: success()
                });

             function success(){
                $("#sent-form-msg").fadeIn();
                $("#sent-form-msg").fadeOut(5500).html("<p align='center'>Avaliação Submetida com sucesso! Obrigado pelo seu voto</p>");;
             }

            return false;                    
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Stars

```
                <div class="rate-ex1-cnt">
                    <div id="1" class="rate-btn-1 rate-btn"></div>
                    <div id="2" class="rate-btn-2 rate-btn"></div>
                    <div id="3" class="rate-btn-3 rate-btn"></div>
                    <div id="4" class="rate-btn-4 rate-btn"></div>
                    <div id="5" class="rate-btn-5 rate-btn"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="sent-form-msg"></div>
```

Php Code

require_once("../gtm/bd/funcoes.php");
ligarBd();

```
if($_REQUEST['act'] == 'rate'){
    //search if the user(ip) has already gave a note
    $user = $_POST['user_id'];
    $pontos = $_POST['rate'];
    $estabelecimento_id = $_POST['post_id'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM avaliacoes where user_id= '".$user."  "); 
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $rate_db[] = $data;
    }

    if(@count($rate_db) == 0 ){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO avaliacoes (user_id, estabelecimento_id, pontos)VALUES('".$user.", '".$estabelecimento_id.", '".$pontos.")");
    }else{
        mysql_query("UPDATE avaliacoes SET pontos= '".$pontos." WHERE user_id = '".$user."");
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the PHP part

Comment: already put up the php code

Comment: in your DB is `pontos` set up as an integer value? what about `user_id`? putting the values in apostrophe's might not be good to your insert  (not to metion you have apostrophe mistakes in there) `VALUES(".$user.", ".$estabelecimento_id.", ".$pontos.")")` would work better than `VALUES('".$user.", '".$estabelecimento_id.", '".$pontos.")")`

Comment: friend was worth even these quotes that were ill fix and already works thanks for the help

Comment: plus a small thing can help me how can I verify that the Highscore utlizador voted and show the stars selected when the user is logged in